how to use gt() with long tables and pdf
GT does not seem to output long tables (breaking them over multiple pages) although it requires (recommends) the longtable latex package.
So I have been writing a report and, working in R, using gtsummary and gt to format my tables. My problem is that although gt supports latex/pdf output, any table that is longer than one page will overflow. There is seemingly no way to alter gt´s latex output (by for instance using longtable = TRUE or something)
MWE below:
    ---
    title: "Test document"
    subtitle: "TEST DOCUMENT"
    date: today
    toc: true
    format: 
      pdf:
        header-includes:
        - \usepackage{booktabs, caption, longtable, colortbl, array}
        keep-tex: true
    ---
    
    # Baseline table
    
    ```{r}
    library(tidyverse)
    library(gt)
    
    tibble(
        variable = paste0("var", 1:80),
        value = runif(80),
        test = runif(80)
    ) %>% gt()
    
    ```

Which produces this output:

Does anyone know how this can be resolved? I would really like to use gt, but it seemingly has some quite big disadvantages. Any resources better describing gt-quarto-latex is very welcome.
EDIT: typo removed

Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Just add tab_options(latex.use_longtable = TRUE) to your {gt} object, like:
tibble(
  variable = paste0("var", 1:80),
  value = runif(80),
  test = runif(80)
) %>% gt() |>
  tab_options(latex.use_longtable = TRUE)


See: https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_options.html

This is exactly what I was looking for - many thanks. I cannot believe I couldn't find it myself (I googled for a full day, maybe more).

As quarto doc with pdf-ouput you can use kableExtra like this:
---
title: "Test document"
subtitle: "TEST DOCUMENT"
date: today
toc: true
format: pdf

---


```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
library(gt)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)

# Sample data
data <- tibble(
  variable = paste0("var", 1:80),
  value = runif(80),
  test = runif(80)
)

# Create a longtable
data %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = TRUE, longtable = TRUE, caption = "such a looong boy") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat_header"))
```



Try the stargazer package in R:
library(stargazer)

stargazer(df, type = "text",
summary = F,
row names = F,
title = "[You title here]",
out = "table_output.txt") # You can create a file

For the full list of functions for stargazer, follow this link: Stargazer Package
